# how to use the usercache with custom daoauthenticationprovider

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-security, ehcache

I need to make use of the usercache provided by spring but cannot seem to get it to work. As far as I can see, I dont even think my implementation of the userdetailsService is being picked up when using it as a reference in the daoAuthenticationProvider (whose functionality I seek to use).  I have done the following:

1) Implemented UserDetailsInterface using my own HibernateDao

2) Provided my own loadbyusername(String username) method as stipulated by point 1

3) Configure my app-context :

```
<beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder"/>

<beans:bean id="userCache" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.cache.EhCacheBasedUserCache">
    <beans:property name="cache" ref="userCacheBackend"/>
</beans:bean>   

<beans:bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
     <beans:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/ehcache.xml"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userCacheBackend" class="rg.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
    <beans:property name="cacheName" value="userCache"/>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDao">
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" /> 
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDao"/>
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/> 
        <beans:property name="userCache" ref="userCache"/>
</beans:bean>
```

However, despite setting my userDao as the userDetailsService property name I cant seem to make use of any of the functionality provided by the DaoAuthenticationProvider and AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider classes that implement the UserDetailsService interface (which will be my HibernateDao).

Here is my hibernate dao:

```
@Repository("userDao")
public class HibernateUserDao extends HibernateBaseDao<User, Long> implements
    UserDao, UserDetailsService{ etc ....................

@Transactional

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    logger.warn(" loadByUserName has been invoked for username " + username);
    List users = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().
            createQuery("from User where username=?")
            .setParameter(0, username).list();
    if (users == null || users.isEmpty()) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user '" + username
                + "' not found...");
    } else {
        return (UserDetails) users.get(0); 
    }
}
```

Am I doing something really dumb? Please help Ive gone mad.

Comment: the HibernateUserDao is autowired but I dont think this would have any impact.

Comment: do you have <context:component-scan base-package="yourpackage"/> defined for spring annotation to pick up your respository annotation

Comment: yes I do. It is as follows 
 <!-- Activates scanning of @Repository -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="package.name.is.here" />